# NoClassDefFoundError: Appears on runtime in sbt multi-project, The error appear when I hit any URL after running my project

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a multi-sbt project, which has projects like invoices-and-orders, order-dtos.
We use internally made libraries in our organization.

The error appears at runtime after I hit any resource, I have researched a bit on how classLoader, etc work in loading classes at runtime in java, but I don't understand the root cause of this issue.

I would be thankful if someone could provide insights on this issue.

Full Stack Trace is as follows

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoClassDefFoundError: order/dtos/internal/DPQSRepresentations$DPQSStrategy]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:184)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: order/dtos/internal/DPQSRepresentations$DPQSStrategy
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:929)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: order.dtos.internal.DPQSRepresentations$DPQSStrategy
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:929)
```

order/dtos/internal/DPQSRepresentations is the class object in order-dtos project

Comment: It's a sbt multi-project not multi-site project, as someone edited.

Comment: Usually, one gets a CNF Exception when the class in question is not on the classpath. How is your project layed out? Did you use `dependsOn` in your build.sbt?